# Schematic editor does not produce clickable image

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Whilst editing [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/395780/logic-circuit-shutting-off-at-target-voltage), I noticed that the schematic markdown (produced by the schematic editor on SE.Electronics (and maybe elsewhere that it is employed))  displays an image that is not clickable, as the code shows below:

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nK9.png)

<!-- End schematic -->
```

Would it not be preferable to produce this code, in order to result in a clickable/expandable schematic? After all, if I right click and display the schematic in another tab, it is displayed much larger.

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

[![schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nK9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nK9.png)

<!-- End schematic -->
```

Or, preferably, this less messy version:

```
<!-- Begin schematic: In order to preserve an editable schematic, please
     don't edit this section directly.
     Click the "edit" link below the image in the preview instead. -->

[![schematic][1]][1]

<!-- End schematic -->

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7nK9.png
```

It would seem possible to manually edit the markdown, produced by the schematic editor, in order to obtain a clickable image but at the risk of making the schematic no longer editable (if the warning message is to be believed).

---

Also, without wishing to raise two issues in one post, note the use of `http` and not `https` - I could post a different question relating to this issue, if necessary

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Inserting an image with the toolbar (shortcut: control + g) already produces the "less messy version". However, nothing stops anyone from editing the markdown to remove the link.

Comment: This is about the schematic editor employed on SE.Electronics (and maybe elsewhere)